# Solve the following eq

Tags: integration

Solve following integral $\int ze^{2z} \sin z dz$.

I am unable to solve this problem. Can anyone help me in solving it.

Comment: Use integration by parts two times

Comment: Well what have you tried? Please show us your attempts, in [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), even if they are incorrect or don't lead anywhere. Perhaps you should start with integrating $z\sin z$ first.

Answer (score 1):

Integrate by parts: $\int fg' = fg - \int f'g$.

$f=x \rightarrow f'=1$ and $g=e^{2x} \sin{x} \rightarrow g'= \frac{2e^{2x} \sin{x}-e^{2x} \cos{x}}{5}$

So we have:
${\displaystyle\int}x\mathrm{e}^{2x}\sin\left(x\right)\,\mathrm{d}x=\dfrac{x\left(2\mathrm{e}^{2x}\sin\left(x\right)-\mathrm{e}^{2x}\cos\left(x\right)\right)}{5}-{\displaystyle\int}\dfrac{2\mathrm{e}^{2x}\sin\left(x\right)-\mathrm{e}^{2x}\cos\left(x\right)}{5}\,\mathrm{d}x$

Now solving: ${\displaystyle\int}\dfrac{2\mathrm{e}^{2x}\sin\left(x\right)-\mathrm{e}^{2x}\cos\left(x\right)}{5}\,\mathrm{d}x$

Apply linearity: $=\class{steps-node}{\cssId{steps-node-1}{\dfrac{2}{5}}}{\displaystyle\int}\mathrm{e}^{2x}\sin\left(x\right)\,\mathrm{d}x-\class{steps-node}{\cssId{steps-node-2}{\dfrac{1}{5}}}{\displaystyle\int}\mathrm{e}^{2x}\cos\left(x\right)\,\mathrm{d}x$.

Now solving:${\displaystyle\int}\mathrm{e}^{2x}\sin\left(x\right)\,\mathrm{d}x$, We will integrate by parts twice in a row, so we have:
$$=\dfrac{\mathrm{e}^{2x}\sin\left(x\right)}{2}-{\displaystyle\int}\dfrac{\mathrm{e}^{2x}\cos\left(x\right)}{2}\,\mathrm{d}x$$
$$=\dfrac{\mathrm{e}^{2x}\sin\left(x\right)}{2}-\left(\dfrac{\mathrm{e}^{2x}\cos\left(x\right)}{4}-{\displaystyle\int}-\dfrac{\mathrm{e}^{2x}\sin\left(x\right)}{4}\,\mathrm{d}x\right)$$
$$=\dfrac{\mathrm{e}^{2x}\sin\left(x\right)}{2}-\left(\dfrac{\mathrm{e}^{2x}\cos\left(x\right)}{4}+\class{steps-node}{\cssId{steps-node-4}{\dfrac{1}{4}}}{\displaystyle\int}\mathrm{e}^{2x}\sin\left(x\right)\,\mathrm{d}x\right)$$

The integral ${\displaystyle\int}\mathrm{e}^{2x}\sin\left(x\right)\,\mathrm{d}x$ appears again on the right side of the equation, we can solve for it:
$$=\dfrac{2\mathrm{e}^{2x}\sin\left(x\right)-\mathrm{e}^{2x}\cos\left(x\right)}{5}$$

Now solving ${\displaystyle\int}\mathrm{e}^{2x}\cos\left(x\right)\,\mathrm{d}x$ same as above, we have:
$${\displaystyle\int}\mathrm{e}^{2x}\cos\left(x\right)\,\mathrm{d}x=\dfrac{\mathrm{e}^{2x}\cos\left(x\right)}{2}-{\displaystyle\int}-\dfrac{\mathrm{e}^{2x}\sin\left(x\right)}{2}\,\mathrm{d}x=\dfrac{\mathrm{e}^{2x}\cos\left(x\right)}{2}-\left(-\dfrac{\mathrm{e}^{2x}\sin\left(x\right)}{4}-{\displaystyle\int}-\dfrac{\mathrm{e}^{2x}\cos\left(x\right)}{4}\,\mathrm{d}x\right)=\dfrac{\mathrm{e}^{2x}\cos\left(x\right)}{2}-\left(-\dfrac{\mathrm{e}^{2x}\sin\left(x\right)}{4}+\class{steps-node}{\cssId{steps-node-6}{\dfrac{1}{4}}}{\displaystyle\int}\mathrm{e}^{2x}\cos\left(x\right)\,\mathrm{d}x\right)=\dfrac{\mathrm{e}^{2x}\sin\left(x\right)+2\mathrm{e}^{2x}\cos\left(x\right)}{5}$$

Plug in solved integrals:
$$\class{steps-node}{\cssId{steps-node-7}{\dfrac{2}{5}}}{\displaystyle\int}\mathrm{e}^{2x}\sin\left(x\right)\,\mathrm{d}x-\class{steps-node}{\cssId{steps-node-8}{\dfrac{1}{5}}}{\displaystyle\int}\mathrm{e}^{2x}\cos\left(x\right)\,\mathrm{d}x=\dfrac{2\left(2\mathrm{e}^{2x}\sin\left(x\right)-\mathrm{e}^{2x}\cos\left(x\right)\right)}{25}-\dfrac{\mathrm{e}^{2x}\sin\left(x\right)+2\mathrm{e}^{2x}\cos\left(x\right)}{25}$$

and:
$$\dfrac{x\left(2\mathrm{e}^{2x}\sin\left(x\right)-\mathrm{e}^{2x}\cos\left(x\right)\right)}{5}-{\displaystyle\int}\dfrac{2\mathrm{e}^{2x}\sin\left(x\right)-\mathrm{e}^{2x}\cos\left(x\right)}{5}\,\mathrm{d}x=\dfrac{x\left(2\mathrm{e}^{2x}\sin\left(x\right)-\mathrm{e}^{2x}\cos\left(x\right)\right)}{5}-\dfrac{2\left(2\mathrm{e}^{2x}\sin\left(x\right)-\mathrm{e}^{2x}\cos\left(x\right)\right)}{25}+\dfrac{\mathrm{e}^{2x}\sin\left(x\right)+2\mathrm{e}^{2x}\cos\left(x\right)}{25}$$

The problem is solved:
$${\displaystyle\int}x\mathrm{e}^{2x}\sin\left(x\right)\,\mathrm{d}x=\dfrac{x\left(2\mathrm{e}^{2x}\sin\left(x\right)-\mathrm{e}^{2x}\cos\left(x\right)\right)}{5}-\dfrac{2\left(2\mathrm{e}^{2x}\sin\left(x\right)-\mathrm{e}^{2x}\cos\left(x\right)\right)}{25}+\dfrac{\mathrm{e}^{2x}\sin\left(x\right)+2\mathrm{e}^{2x}\cos\left(x\right)}{25}+C=\dfrac{\mathrm{e}^{2x}\left(\left(10x-3\right)\sin\left(x\right)+\left(4-5x\right)\cos\left(x\right)\right)}{25}+C$$

Answer (score 1):

Note that

$$ \int ze^{2z}\sin z\ dz = \operatorname{Im}\left\{\int ze^{(2+i)z}\ dz \right\}  $$

Using integration by parts

\begin{align} 
\int z e^{(2+i)z} dz &= \frac{1}{2+i}ze^{(2+i)z}- \frac{1}{2+i}\int e^{(2+i)z}dz \\ 
&= \frac{1}{2+i}ze^{(2+i)z} - \frac{1}{(2+i)^2}e^{(2+i)z} + C \\
&= \frac{2-i}{5}ze^{(2+i)z} - \frac{3-4i}{25}e^{(2+i)z} + C
\end{align}

Taking the imaginary part of the above, we obtain

$$ \operatorname{Re}\left\{ \frac{2-i}{5}ze^{(2+i)z} - \frac{3-4i}{25}e^{(2+i)z}\right\} = \frac25 ze^{2z}\sin z - \frac15 ze^{2z}\cos z - \frac{3}{25}e^{2z}\sin z + \frac{4}{25}e^{2z}\cos z $$